# Question on the use of the Markov Kernel for conditional probability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, conditional-expectation

We define a Markov kernel:

> Let $(\Omega_{1},\mathcal{A}_{1})$ and $(\Omega_{2},\mathcal{A}_{2})$ be some measurable spaces. A map $K$ where $K : \Omega_{1}\times \mathcal{A}_{2}\to [0,\infty]$ is called a Markov kernel if,
>
> $1.$ For all $A\in \mathcal{A}_{2}$, the map $$K(\cdot,A):\Omega_{1}\to [0,\infty],\; \omega_{1}\mapsto K(\omega_{1},A)$$ is a $\mathcal{A}_{1}$ measurable.
>
> $2.$ For all $\omega_{1} \in \Omega_{1}$, the map $$K(\omega,\cdot):  \mathcal{A}_{2} \to [0,\infty], \; A \mapsto K(\omega,A)$$ is a probability measure.

In our lecture, the Markov kernel was introduced in order to find a "satisfying" expression for the conditional probability $P(A\lvert \mathcal{F})$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is some sub-$\sigma$-field in a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$. I have to truly understand what "satisfying" means in this sense. The reason given in the lecture is that viewing the conditional probability operator given $\mathcal{F}$ as an operator on $\Omega\times \mathcal{A}$, a continuous model can have uncountably many events $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and it is not clear whether the choice of null-sets remains plaubsible in order to obtain a probability measure in the event argument, since an uncountable union of null sets need not be a null set.

My issue: I do not understand the problem here. Surely, we have the exact same issue in the unconditional case: the uncountable union of null sets need not be a null set. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some problems with the other answer, so let me offer something different.

First of all, contrary to what the other answer says, conditional probabilities *do* satisfy the measurability constraint (1) on Markov kernels. This is just part of their definition.

The key thing to realize is that, for conditional probabilities, there could be a set $F$ with positive measure such that $P(\cdot \mid \mathcal F)(\omega)$ is not a probability measure for all $\omega \in F$.

How can this happen? Well, what does it mean to be a probability measure? The key property is:

*Additivity:* $P$ is a probability measure if $P(\cup_{j=1}^n A_j) = \sum_{j=1}^n P(A_j)$ for all pairwise disjoint sequences $A_1,...,A_n$ in $\mathcal A$.

Now, using the definition of conditional probability, it is easy to show that for every pairwise disjoint sequence $\mathscr A = A_1,...,A_n$, there is a null set $F_{\mathscr A}$ such that $P(\cup_{j=1}^n A_j \mid \mathcal F)(\omega) = \sum_{j=1}^n P(A_j \mid \mathcal F)(\omega)$ whenever $\omega \notin F_{\mathscr A}$.

Now ask yourself: How many sequences $\mathscr A$ of pairwise disjoint events are there in a large probability space? It's easy to convince yourself (consider Lebesgue measure, for instance) that in general there must be uncountably many such $\mathscr A$. And that means there are uncountably many sets $F_{\mathscr A}$ on which the conditional probability *fails* to be a probability measure.

Thus, the set $F$ where the conditional probability fails to be a probability measure includes
$$\bigcup_{\mathscr A} F_{\mathscr A},$$
which, although each $F_{\mathscr{A}}$ is null, may have positive measure because it's an uncountable union.

To me, this is the key point that the other answer did not convey.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks!